# How to create a global pointer variable for a custom structure in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I define a structure in the header file types.h:

```
typedef struct{
char str [10].
void *p.
}for_test;
```

In Pass, I first refer to the header file. I want to create a global pointer in pass to access the structured array.

```
#include ".. /types.h"
...
static StructType *fp_type = llvm::StructType::getTypeByName(C,"for_test");
GlobalVariable *F_Pointer = new GlobalVariable(
M, PointerType::get (fp_type, 0), false,
GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 0, "f_p");
```

However, PointerType::get (fp_type,0) has an error and I don’t know how to fix it.
Error:

[image]

Comment: Well, what error?

Comment: I have updated the post with the error. I am not entirely sure that this is due to Pointers in the global variable, but I am sure that everything worked well before I added the global variable.

Comment: Note that a GlobalVariable is space to store said global. If you create new `GlobalVariable *GV = new GlobalVariable(...)` with `i32` type, then `GV` has type of `i32*` not `i32`. It's a pointer to where to store the data.

Comment: Is `fp_type` nullptr here? Or is it valid? Try building LLVM with assertions enabled? Is `fp_type` a function-local static variable and if so are you sure it's still a valid pointer (i.e. you're using your pass on the same LLVMContext every time)?